# VBA Code fails to copy some worksheets, message "Permission denied" appears

Tags: excel, vba, windows, runtime-error

I have run this macro since I remember and it never failed before, today it failed to copy 4 worksheets into a new file, returning a "Permission denied" error

There's no many information about this issue, so what I've tried is pretty much to check that I am running everything on admin user, to run Excel as administrator. However, it only fails with .xlsm files, the others work fine

The code fails on the first line, when the `Copy` command is used. It is supposed to create a new workbook with those sheets copied. Instead, the "Permission denied" error shows, and at the end it shows ": \name.temp" where name starts with 'VB' and some numbers after that, the numbers always change whenever I try it again.

```
Worksheets(Array("POS", "VAL", "COL2(USD)", "COL2(PS)")).Copy 
Sheets("POS").Select
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("VAL").Select
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("COL2(USD)").Select
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Sheets("COL2(USD)").Select
Cells.Copy
Cells.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: What line is the error happening on? Also, you shouldn't be using select statements. see... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Comment: I'm sorry, it's on the first line, where I array the worksheets and tell to copy them. It doesn't create any workbook and it alwasy says "Permission denied: \name.temp" where name it's always some numbers and letters starting with 'VB'

Comment: So you've lost write permissions to a folder, and now Excel cannot create a temp file for the new workbook. Does it give you full path to that folder? If it does not, grab [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) and find out yourself.

Comment: It doesn't give me any full paths. I have not used process monitor so far, so I will download it and try this solution. Is it possible for this to happen even though no changes were made from one day to another? @GSerg

Comment: @CarlosCasio It's about changes to your file system and/or Excel default folders paths, not the macro.

Comment: @GSerg precisely, I meant there were no changes on aything, not in Windows nor in Excel. Actually it only fails when I use .xlsm files, and it doesn't matter if I try to copy the sheets with or without a macro, it will show the same error. It seems really weird to me, I will chec the prcomon tho.